# How to reduce UDP sendto delay in Linux?

Tags: sockets, network-programming

We are streaming udp packets from a Linux PC over 10Gb Ethernet at high data rate. We are coding in C++.

When we call sendto() to send a udp packet, are there any optimisations we can make regarding the actual latency of transmission, i.e. how quickly the packet actually gets sent?

Does the concept of flushing apply to a UDP send buffer, or are UDP packets always sent immediately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UDP packets are normally only buffered when there is congestion on the outgoing interface.  You might be able to reduce the latency under load by:

- reducing the size of the socket's buffer (`setsockopt(SO_SNDBUF)`);
- reducing the size of the buffer associated with the interface (`tc qdisc change`);
- reducing the size of the driver's internal buffers (driver-specific).

Note that doing that will reduce latency under load by dropping packets instead of buffering them, so, depending on your higher-layer protocols, it might actually *increase* application latency, e.g. by causing increased application-layer retransmissions.